# Setting up VNC on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, vnc

I have setup "Remote Management" on a Mac OS X system (running 10.5.8). Trying to connect with a VNC client results in messages like "No supported authentication types" (VineViewer) or "Unknown authType" (Chicken of the VNC).

It's not a firewall issue, since I opened that up. Any suggestions, ideas?

**Edit** Same issue happens whether I try to connect from the machine itself or from another machine that can ping it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to **enable Screen Sharin**g instead of Remote Management, to enable VNC access.

FYI: there's an integrated VNC viewer in OS X:

1. Open the Finder a
2. Hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> **or**
   select *Connect to Server* from the
   *Go* Menu in the Menubar.
3. Enter `vnc://ip.of.remote.machine` and
   click connect.

Comment: Screen Sharing and Remote Management ultimately have all the same RFB options.

Comment: That worked, thanks lajuette! I mean, I didn't change anything on the VNC "server," I just connected via the Finder on the guest.

Comment: @VxJasonxV: Thanks for the tip. I didn't know that.

Comment: @Yar: Just because I'm curious. Did you enter a username and password? Or only a username.

Comment: Ugh. Sigh. Last question was: "Or only a password?"

Comment: @VxJasonX, not sure what happened. I think I never came back to superuser, which is a huge time suck :)... anyway, the answer is... I don't remember. Sorry :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that by default, OS X expects to get a username AND password for authentication, while standard VNC clients just send a password.  Connecting from the OS X Finder (/Screen Sharing util) works because that knows how to send both the username and password.  If you want to connect from standard clients, you need to set a VNC compatibility password (which can be used without a username) in System Preferences -> Sharing -> Screen Sharing or Remote Management -> Computer Settings -> "VNC viewers may control screen with password:".

Side note: the "Screen Sharing" and "Remote Management" services are essentially the same thing -- the difference is that Remote Management ALSO enables Apple Remote Desktop features (e.g. report generation, file transfer, etc).