# MacOSX SSVNC Darwin not found

Tags: macos, mac, vnc

I'm trying to install SSVNC on my Mac. I download file witch SSVNC for all platforms, unzip it. Than I tried to run file sshvnc in MacOSX, but it wrote me this error:

> Cannot find platform dir for your OS Darwin x86_64:
>
> /Users/jankozusnik/Downloads/ssvnc/bin/Darwin.x86_64 vncviewer not
>   found in PATH. stunnel not found in PATH.
>
> You can set the $UNAME env. var. to override the OS setting. Or, if
>   available, run the ./build.unix script to build it. Or install
>   external "vncviewer" and "stunnel" packages. logout

What to do with this?

I also tried to use Chicken of the VNC, but it gives me this error "Unknowh AuthType 19", however I allowed in Sharing "Remote management"

Do you know, how to solve my problem?

Thank you very much for your opinions and time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be Darwin.x86_64 directory under the bin directory.  I downloaded a copy and verified that was the case. (Got the same message with a path to where it was located on my Desktop).

From the Apple Screen Sharing App help file (under **About Screen Sharing** in OS X 10.6) -

> OS X screen sharing, and Apple Remote Desktop screen sharing, are
>   compatible with Virtual Network Computing (VNC), an industry standard
>   for controlling computers remotely on a network using TCP/IP.

The Screen Sharing App is found in `/System/Library/CoreServices/`.  Give it a try, It'll likely perform better.  Chicken of the VNC had a problem logging on in OS X 10.6 or 10.7 as I recall.

I've used it between an OS X 10.9.4 host and a 10.6 VM (on the same Mac).  I'd imagine the Screen Sharing App is at least in part responsible for the lack of recent vnc releases for recent OS X versions.

Also see [Setting up VNC on Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/186775/setting-up-vnc-on-mac-os-x).  The answer shows how to invoke a vnc connection fairly painlessly.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to help myself with the link you posted. But, if it is trying to find out Darwin.x86_64 when it is not in the downloaded file? Where is the problem?
EDIT: I find out that the link you posted I found few days before and it didn't helped me :/

Comment: I think the implication is that if you want a Darwin x86_64 ssvnc executable you're going to half to compile it your self from source. I'd suggest you try using the OS X built in vnc client.

Comment: Thank you David. How to use built in vnc klient? Did you mean: Finder -> Cmd + K ??

Comment: Cmd + K is the easiest way. You could also drag /System/Library/CoreServices/Screen Sharing.app to you're dock or create a link so it shows up.  Also must have Screen Sharing checked in Preferences > Sharing, and acceptable permissions in under Allow Access for:, there.

Comment: Ask a question, get an answer.